# qmake: Use flags from pkg-config if they exist, otherwise use defaults

Tags: qt, qmake, pkg-config

In my setup, I want to support both system-wide Qt installations and custom Qt installations. I can use `pkg-config` to get the correct compile and link flags for my system-wide installation:

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += Qt5Core
```

However, if `pkg-config` cannot find `Qt5Core`, the build will fail with `Project ERROR: Qt5Core development package not found`.

Instead of failing, I want to set reasonable defaults (e.g. `/usr/local/qt5`). It should achieve the following:

```
if pkg-config can find Qt5Core {
    PKGCONFIG += Qt5Core
} else {
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/qt5/
    LIBS += -lQt5Core
}
```

How can I accomplish this in my project configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a qmake function for this:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#packagesexist-packages

```
packagesExist(Qt5Core) {
    PKGCONFIG += Qt5Core
} else {
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/qt5/
    LIBS += -lQt5Core
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#system-command) built-in test function which `executes the given command in a secondary shell. Succeeds if the command returns with a zero exit status; otherwise fails.`

```
system(pkg-config --exists Qt5Core) {
    PKGCONFIG += Qt5Core
} else {
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/qt5/
    LIBS += -lQt5Core
}
```